# Nested CSS styles?

Tags: css, selector

Is something like this possible?

```
.imgbox:hover{ .ui-resizable-se { /*some style */ } }
```

Or a conceptual equivalent?
Basically, only when an element of a certain class is hovered over, then some element *within* that class should change some style.

Comment: No. Not without [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: .imgbox:hover .ui-resizable-se { /*some style */ } Ignore the less/sass answers - they misunderstand the extremely simply problem and shoot canon balls at your fly. Not saying anything against sass/less, but whether to use that or not is a WHOLE other issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
.imgbox:hover .ui-resizable-se { /*some style */ }
```

The same can be generated by LESS or SASS.

Answer (score 2):

Sure that would be :

```
.imgbox:hover .ui-resizable-se { /*some style */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, CSS does not allow nesting. You'd have to write it like this:

```
.imgbox:hover .ui-resizable-se { /*some style */ }
```

However, there are various CSS preprocessors available which convert something like this in valid CSS. The most popular ones are [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Not with plain CSS but you can with a CSS preprocessor like Sass:

http://sass-lang.com/

```
table.hl {
  margin: 2em 0;
  td.ln {
    text-align: right;
  }
}

li {
  font: {
    family: serif;
    weight: bold;
    size: 1.2em;
  }
}
```

Generates:

```
/* CSS */

table.hl {
  margin: 2em 0;
}
table.hl td.ln {
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```